# Two way binding in select using ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use ng-options in select to iterate over an array.This select is basically used as a question navigator.I want to use two way data binding.Actually I have an array of questions and displaying one question in one page.So the question at the zeroth index should be selected when the page no is 0 and vice versa.I'm getting a blank option in the select and on selecting an other question it does not navigate to the respective page.Here is my code-

```
 <select ng-model="liveCtrl.currentPage" ng-options="question.question for (index,question) in liveCtrl.questions track by index" ng-selected="index===liveCtrl.currentPage"></select>
```

Comment: Can you add a `Page` property to your `question` objects in `liveCtrl.questions`?

Comment: actually its coming from the database